# How to color a responsive table in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="SearchCustomerStyle.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Header-->
<div class="container">
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="EyeofHeaven.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown active">
                    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Search<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Search Form(Customer)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Search Form(Vehicle)</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>

<!-- Search form customer-->
<div class="searchcustomer">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item active"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span><span> Search Customer</span></li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
        <input type="text" size="20" class="form-control" placeholder="Search ID">
        </li>        
        <li class="list-group-item">
        <select class="form-control" id="Regions">
            <option>Regions</option>
        </select>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
        <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>Search Info</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- Information Table-->
<div class="bs-example">
    <div class="table-responsive"> 
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Row</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Biography</th>
                    <th>Biography</th>
                    <th>Biography</th>
                    <th>Biography</th>
                    <th>Biography</th>
                    <th>Biography</th>
                    <th>Biography</th>
                    <th>Biography</th><th>Biography</th><th>Biography</th><th>Biography</th><th>Biography</th><th>Biography</th><th>Biography</th><th>Biography</th><th>Biography</th><th>Biography</th><th>Biography</th><th>Biography</th><th>Biography</th><th>Biography</th><th>Biography</th><th>Biography</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>Carter</td>
                    <td>johncarter@mail.com</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Peter</td>
                    <td>Parker</td>
                    <td>peterparker@mail.com</td>
                    <td>Vestibulum consectetur scelerisque lacus, ac fermentum lorem convallis sed. Nam odio tortor, dictum quis malesuada at, pellentesque.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>Rambo</td>
                    <td>johnrambo@mail.com</td>
                    <td>Integer pulvinar leo id risus pellentesque vestibulum. Sed diam libero, sodales eget sapien vel, porttitor bibendum enim.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>Rambo</td>
                    <td>johnrambo@mail.com</td>
                    <td>Integer pulvinar leo id risus pellentesque vestibulum. Sed diam libero, sodales eget sapien vel, porttitor bibendum enim.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>Rambo</td>
                    <td>johnrambo@mail.com</td>
                    <td>Integer pulvinar leo id risus pellentesque vestibulum. Sed diam libero, sodales eget sapien vel, porttitor bibendum enim.</td>
                </tr>               
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css code:

```
body{
    background:url(blurbubble.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
.list-group{
    width: 200px;
}
.searchcustomer{
    margin-top:51px;
}
    .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
    }
thead, tbody { display: block; }
tbody {
    width:500px;
    height: 100px;       /* Just for the demo          */
    overflow-y: auto;    /* Trigger vertical scroll    */
    overflow-x: hidden;  /* Hide the horizontal scroll */
}
.table-responsive{
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin-top:-220px;
    margin-left:200px;
    max-width: auto;
}
```

[image: This is the images that I import to make a background]

How do I make my table to set a color background to white, when I put my table into the webpage, my table background is also the background image that i set into the body. How do I set the background color of my table to white?

Comment: [Consider providing a SSCCE, emphasis on the *short*](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I believe it should be just `.table-responsive{  { background-color: white; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just, use **[`background-color`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp)**

**CSS:**

```
.table-responsive{
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin-top:-220px;
    margin-left:200px;
    max-width: auto;
    background-color: white; // Can use hexadecimal color here too (#FFFFFF)
}
```

**[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/aqzf2p28/1/)**

**Update @media:**

```
@media all and (max-width: 1028px ){
    body {
        background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DafcS.jpg) no-repeat;
        background-size: contain 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: It work sir, thank you. Hmm, How do I change my background image to make my background-size 100 percent sir? If I access this on mobile the background will not entirely fit my webpage.

Comment: You can use [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) for this and manipulate the background.

Answer (score 0):

Use css `background-color: white;`

Comment: Oh I get it you can't change image background you have to use image edit application instead

Answer (score 0):

You either need to update the css for .table or add a new class to your table tag and add the following css to it:

```
background-color: white;
```